# Elements 'twitching slightly' when implementing scroll anchoring

Tags: javascript, css

EDIT: Embarrassingly, I originally saw this issue on Chrome but the issue was because I was slightly zoomed out on the browser causing subpixel element sizing. If the elements are full pixel heights it works fine. However, I believe this is still an issue as Firefox seems to render sub-pixel elements differently to Chrome and also we should support zooming.

I'm trying to implement [scroll-anchoring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor) cross-browser so that when appending a new element to an overflow container and the user is scrolled up, the position won't move.

I have a test codepen here: https://codepen.io/djdmorrison/pen/YzpwvWx

I'm restricting the container to contain 50 elements, adding a new one every 250ms and removing the oldest at the same time. When the user is scrolled mid-way in the container I want the elements to stay still.

I do this by getting the `container.scrollTop` and `container.scrollHeight` before the new element is added. I then add the element, take the `container.scrollHeight` again and work out the difference in the scrollHeight (to work out the difference in heights of the new element added and the old removed). I then set the `container.scrollTop` to the previous `scrollTop` minus the new elements height (+ margin) plus + the difference in scroll heights: `container.scrollTop = beforeScrollTop - (newEl.offsetHeight + margin) + diffScrollHeight;`

This seems to be the solution almost, but there's a very slightly twitching, especially on firefox.

What am I missing?