# Force browser to render elements with integer pixels

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a CSS trick to force browsers to render elements in integer pixels rather than sub-pixels? For example, Chrome may show an element's width as 80px, but Firefox shows as 80.25px.

Easy with JavaScript (`` element.style.height = `${element.offsetHeight}px`; ``) as browsers seem to respect the value set in the style attribute and `offsetHeight` rounds, but I imagine calling `offsetHeight` would cause some layout thrashing, and I plan to do this on a large number of elements.

Comment: in a generic way or you have a specific case ?

Comment: I have a specific case but I guess in a  general way. I asked another question earlier (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66062867/elements-twitching-slightly-when-implementing-scroll-anchoring) which I have found is due to sub-pixel rendering on Firefox.

Comment: An answer to this might help several other recent queries too - e.g. 'stray' shadows left behind on some transformations which seem to be 'part' CSS pixels (= to 1 whole screen pixel possibly). Hope someone knows the answer.